# React-Native android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, react-native

App middle native Player(C++) built with `NDK 13b` version and uses `libgnustl-shared.so` build with it. React native uses a different version of NDK and `libgnustl-shared.so` comes with it(NDK 10e version) has conflicts with the one I use for my middleware libs. Is there a way I can resolve this? the lib used for the app is not accepted by react-native and the `react-native-based` lib is not compatible with my middleware libs. I can not downgrade the NDK used for my native app (to 10e supported for react-native). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct way would be to refer the same version of library across all of the application. But if it is impossible - you may link one module against static version of library while leaving the second one linked against shared as usual.

But such approach is rather a workaround than a real solution. Because there are at least next downsides:

- app size bloates because now you are deploying code for two versions of library instead of one
- objects of the same classes in different library versions may be binary incompatible - so if you try to pass c++ objects between code that relies on different lib version - it ends up with undefined behavior.

At the end: I'd think twice if there is really no way to use the same version everywhere.

Comment: As per my understanding its not possible or its big task if I want to use same lib for both (react-native and myapp). Myapp is huge and was used on different platforms and for android its well maintained using android ndk 13b. But React-native only supports NDK 10e version. Do you see any possibility there to use same lib?

Comment: @Reddy Why should it be impossible? The only way is to choose final version and rebuild inconsistent module using it. What version will you choose and how to rebuild code is completely up to you.

Comment: React-Native says they only support default android NDK which is 10e to build react-native. If I build react-native source with 13b and if its success also there is no possibility that it will work well (few posts suggest some issues). For my app which was built and developed using 13b NDK (its a c++ app just contain native methods to interact). Compiling it downgrading to 10e might not be right path (tried and got some compilation issues). You are right its not impossible but kind of big task as I am just trying to evaluate using React-Native for my app.

Comment: Using two different versions one static for my app leaving the react-native one as it is resolved the issue. As of now things are smooth -Thanks